# Emgu CV error opening .tif image

Tags: opencv, emgucv

Im using emgu surf demo

```
using (Mat modelImage = CvInvoke.Imread("img_1.jpg", LoadImageType.Grayscale))
         using (Mat observedImage = CvInvoke.Imread("f.tif", LoadImageType.Grayscale))
         {
             Mat result = DrawMatches.Draw(modelImage, observedImage, out matchTime, out matchpercent);
             ImageViewer.Show(result, String.Format("Matched using {0} in {1} milliseconds", CudaInvoke.HasCuda ? "GPU" : "CPU", matchTime));
         }
```

An the exception:
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll

What can i do to read .tif images properly?

Comment: Are you sure the file is a proper .tif file? Have you tried opening it in another application? Have you tried feeding it a JPG file instead? What size is the .tif?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, i can open it with other apps. File info: 570x335 and 2,30K

Comment: Check this link might help http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=968